# Freenom (.tk, .ml, cf) to dedicated server

Tags: domains

I have a dedicated debian 7 server with a website on it using apache2.

*How do I point mydomain.tk to my website?

There is an option to "redirect" to an existing URL but how to do it the "clean" way please?

Comment: The same way as any domain, point your domain to the nameservers your host has provided you

Comment: @JohnConde There is no option in the panel to do this. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot.tk  gives you 2 options; Redirect your .tk domain to another domain or "Use DNS" which then acts like any other domain name. These options are presented to you when creating the dot.tk domain.

If you select "Use DNS" you have 2 options which is to either use the dot.tk DNS service or your own.

Using the dot.tk DNS service will give you these options:
[image]

Using your own DNS service will give you these options:
[image]

Comment: I also found it by myself, the problem was that by default, it was not set to freenom dns, which is weird. Thanks